# drupal Newsletter based on taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, emails

I make a content type that called "commission".
And also I have created a Taxonomy called "commission" too.
In the taxonomy we have some terms like "Fun" or "sports" and etc.
When the user want to create commission node, they should choose one of the taxonomy terms.
Now my question is this:
I want a module to make a subscribe link for people that they can subscribe on the content with the just "sport" taxonomy term or "fun" taxonomy term or something else.
It means I need a subscribe Newsletter module based on the Taxonomy terms.
What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Total Subscription](https://www.drupal.org/project/total_subscription) which says :

Total Subscription provides functionality which would allow the user to subscribe to node pages, taxonomy terms, etc. The main feature which distinguishes it from other subscription modules is that it allows subscription for Anonymous along with Authenticated users.

Or you can try [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module as well, which has feature of rules integration so that you can customize it with taxonomy.